# Calling a function with indirect operator

Tags: c, function, indirection

I have two functions that uses indirect operator `*` and need to call the second function from the first function and pass the parameters given to the first function and dubious about if I must to use `*` or `&` to pass the buffer address.

```
char Func1(short Enable, char Event, char *BufferX)
{
    char xResult;

    xResult=Func2(Event, ?BufferX);//* or &
    return xResult;
}

char Func2(char Event, char *BufferX)
{

}
```

The code is C for microcontrollers, not standard C.

Comment: Given these function definitions, you don't have to use either `&` nor `*`, just pass `BufferX`.

Comment: `char *BufferX` here is a pointer to `char`, often meaning a null terminated C string.

Comment: Microcontrollers like semicolons, too!

Comment: Actually `*` is called the _dereference operator_, while `&` is the _address (of) operator_

Comment: @wildplasser I know, but when I realize about my mistake was too late and, in order to edit, I must to change at least 6 characters.

Comment: `return xResult;` is more than 6 characters.

Answer (score 2):

> I have two functions that uses indirect operator `*`

The asterisk `*` can be interpreted as a *dereference operator* in the context of an expression. In the context of a declaration it serves to indicate that the type being declared is a pointer.

> [I] need to call the second function from the first function and pass the parameters given to the first function

Since both types are identical, you do not need to use any operator at all: simply pass the value of the pointer unchanged, like this:

```
xResult=Func2(Event, BufferX);
```

**Note:** It goes without saying that you need a forward declaration of `Func2` in order for this call to be interpreted correctly.

Comment: Are you talking about prototypes? Yes, I have that part clear.

Comment: @E_Blue Yes, that's exactly what I am talking about. Forward declarations and prototypes are the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

let `var` be a pointer..

`*var` means value the pointer refers..

`&var` means the address of the variable var(No matter it is a pointer)

so in this case you need to pass only the variable.

```
xResult=Func2(Event, BufferX);
```

Its because Func2 is asking for a pointer in its second argument. (Not a value, not a address to a pointer.. )

Answer (score 1):

The correct call is:

```
xResult=Func2(Event, /*nothing here*/BufferX);
```

Since your `BufferX` is already of a correct data type you don't have to either de-reference or take an address of it.

Answer (score 1):

`Func2` wants an argument of type `char*`. The type of `BufferX` is already `char*`.

Thus you can just pass `BufferX` straight to `Func2`:

```
xResult = Func2(Event, BufferX);
```

`&BufferX` would give you the address of `BufferX`, of type `char**`, while `*BufferX` would give you the thing that `BufferX` points to, i.e. a `char`.

Comment: Do you tried to write char* instead char** or there's a type char** that I don't know about?

Comment: @E_Blue No I really meant `char**`. The `*` in `type*` means "pointer to", so `char*` = pointer to `char`, and `char**` = pointer to `char*`.

Comment: Pointerception. Never read about it before. Any word to recommend me to perform a search about?

Comment: Well, pointers to pointers are nothing special, especially in C. After all, a pointer is a basic variable, just like an int. And then you have a pointer to that variable.

Answer (score 1):

The code you presented is *not* using the indirection operator, it is using pointer types.  Values having pointer type are the only kind that can be operands of the indirection operator, but that's a separate matter.

Specifically, argument `BufferX` of function `Func1()` has type `char *`, which makes it a pointer to a `char` (presumably it points to the *first* `char` of a longer buffer).

Argument `BufferX` to `Func2()` also has type `char *`.  If it is appropriate to pass on the arguments from `Func1()` to `Func2()`, then you do not need any adornment -- you just want to pass the values you received:

```
xResult = Func2(Event, BufferX);
```